# BigQuery TPC-H Query 13 does not parse correctly

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have being trying TPC-H in BigQuery, all queries works out of the box, except Query 13

```
SELECT
  c_count,
  COUNT(*) AS custdist
FROM (
  SELECT
    c_custkey,
    COUNT(o_orderkey)
  FROM
    customer
  LEFT OUTER JOIN
    orders
  ON
    c_custkey = o_custkey
    AND o_comment NOT LIKE '%special%requests%'
  GROUP BY
    c_custkey) AS c_orders (c_custkey,
    c_count)
GROUP BY
  c_count
ORDER BY
  custdist DESC,
  c_count DESC;
```

I am getting this error
Expected end of input but got "(", it is referring to (c_custkey,  how to fix that
thanks

Comment: 1.) Can you provide a sample data for your 2 tables, `customer` and `orders`? Just so the community can reproduce the issue and perform tests. 2.) What is the expected output or goal of your query? 3.) I'm not very familiar with this line `AS c_orders (c_custkey,c_count)`. Based from my understanding you aliased a subquery and defined `c_custkey` and `c_count` not sure what defining these do. What should we expect here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below instead

```
SELECT
  c_count,
  COUNT(*) AS custdist
FROM (
  SELECT
    c_custkey,
    COUNT(o_orderkey) as c_count
  FROM
    test-187010.TPCH.customer
  LEFT OUTER JOIN
    orders
  ON
    c_custkey = o_custkey
    AND o_comment NOT LIKE '%special%requests%'
  GROUP BY
    c_custkey) AS c_orders 
GROUP BY
  c_count
ORDER BY
  custdist DESC,
  c_count DESC;
```

Comment: thank you, why the initial syntax was not recognized ?